# Ошибка “main metod is not static in class”

Tags: java, static, main

Изучаю Java и столкнулся с проблемой запуска программы.
Я убрал `static` из класса `main`, т.к код не хотел компилироваться, а теперь выдает ошибку

> main metod is not static in class MyDog

```
public class MyDog {    
    class Dog {
        String name;
        int size;
        String breed;

        void bark(){
            System.out.println("Woof!");
        }
    }

    public void main (String[] args) {
        Dog ray=new Dog();
        ray.size=30;
        ray.bark();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если в main написать static при компиляции выдает : non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context     Dog ray=new Dog();”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public static void main(Sting[] args)` и `static class Dog`

Answer (score 1):

У вас класс `Dog` вложен в класс `MyDog`. Обычно при создании экземпляра (объекта) вложенного класса этот экземпляр получает ссылку на экземпляр (объект) внешнего класса. Это нужно для того, чтобы объект вложенного класса имел доступ к переменным объекта внешнего класса. У вас в методе `main` создается объект класса `Dog`: `Dog ray=new Dog();`, но метод `main` -- статический, то есть работает без создания объекта, поэтому ссылка на объект класса `MyDog` не существует. Именно об этом говорит сообщение об ошибке, которое вы привели.

С другой стороны, метод `main` обязан быть статическим, поскольку это точка входа в программу, и программа должна начать работу до того, как вы сможете создать хоть какой-то объект.

Выход -- сделать статическим и вложенный класс. Статические вложенные классы не имеют связи с объектами тех классов, в которые они вложены, и поэтому ссылка на объект внешнего класса им не нужна, то есть их можно создавать в коде статических методов. Именно это и посоветовал вам Sergi.

Другое возможное решение -- описать класс `Dog` не внутри класса `MyDog`, а вне его. Тогда при создании объекта ссылка на объект внешнего класса будет не нужна, т. к. в таком случае для класса `Dog` внешнего класса не существует.